# The domain and search options in resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking

Let's say you have a resolv.conf file that's something like this.

```
nameserver 192.168.0.7
nameserver 192.168.0.8
domain somedomain.local
```

Then let's say you just changed it to this.

```
nameserver 192.168.0.7
nameserver 192.168.0.8
search somedomain.local
```

Would these both do the same thing? Is one slightly better than the other?

Why would declaring both a domain and search not be recommended?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Unix question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of both keywords are probably historically. Only one of them can be specified in the resolv.conf (the parser built into glibc is supposed to use the last one it encounters). The search keyword is slighty more powerful, since it allows multiple entries, and has the ndots option.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any resources for your answer? I could not find anything related to that after doing a quick search.

Answer (score 1):

[`man 5 resolv.conf`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/resolv.conf.5) currently reads:

> The domain directive is an obsolete name for the search directive that handles one search list entry only.

[Stian Skjelstad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804120/2521769) summarized the benefits of using `search` over `domain` nicely.